# How to add active class on load, using the href in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, getelementsbyclassname

I am **adding active class on click**, which will make the clicked `li` item looks selected. After the user clicks the page is reloaded, so you see that the click works, but **after reload is not visible anymore**. I am using location.href. The idea is to check if the current page href could be find in the child elements of the li's. If true, active class should be attached. Below is the code:

```js
function codeAddress() {
  var loc = location.href;
  var locNavs = document.getElementsByClassName("localLi").children;
  //window.alert(locNavs[0].class);
  for (var i = 0; i < locNavs.length; i++) {
    if (locNavs[i].location.href == loc) {
      locNavs[i].className += "active";
    }
  }
}

window.onload = codeAddress;
```

```html
<ul id="menu-develop_menu" class="nav-menu">
  <li id="menu-item-130" class="localLi menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page 
    menu-item-130"><a href="http://xxxxxx/dev/get/">xxx</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I do not want to use localstorage or something else, but this is not working.And I don't completely understand jQuery, so need JavaScript.

How to retain the hightlight class dependent on the href after reload?

Comment: Please provide HTML code. So we can look at structure.

Comment: Logic Question here.  Why are you reloading the page?  Is it necessary for something you are trying to do (in all cases the answer is most likely, no) and in that case I would suggest simply applying/toggling a class on the target element.  And whatever styles you have in your CSS for this elements active class should take over.

Edit: Or, is this simply just an href loading a new page?  And thus, the loading.

Comment: If someone wants to build it out...
If he doesn't want to use storage, the only next genuine approach is to use url detection.  So detect the parameter or path in the url, and style the proper class based on it.

Comment: I added the HTML. I want to reload the page, because after clicking the menu li you reload another page but the whole menu stays and has to be highlited(with active class)

Comment: These things are generally taken care at the server-side not on the client-side. What is at the backend? The active class should be added by the server-side script before sending the HTML to the browser.

Answer (score 0):

First off you need to include a space OR use another method to add the class:

```
locNavs[i].className += " active";
```

OR

```
locNavs[i].classList.add("active"); //polyfill available for older browsers
```

Note: your href MUST match with this method, there might be better ways such as a `data-current="mycurrent"` attribute on a known element such as the `<ul id="menu-develop_menu" class="nav-menu">` you have.

Now given all that you want to check the child 'a' element href attribute.

```js
function codeAddress() {
  var loc = location.href;
  var locNavs = document.getElementsByClassName("localLi");
  //window.alert(locNavs[0].class);
  for (var i = 0; i < locNavs.length; i++) {
    if (locNavs[i].getElementsByTagName('a')[0].getAttribute("href") == loc) {
      locNavs[i].className += " active";
    }
  }
}

window.onload = codeAddress;
```

```html
<ul id="menu-develop_menu" class="nav-menu">
  <li id="menu-item-130" class="localLi menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page 
    menu-item-130"><a href="http://xxxxxx/dev/get/">xxx</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Given all that, this seems to be a "fragile" way to do this.

Test the concept

```js
var testhref = "http://xxxxxx/dev/get/";

function codeAddress() {
  var loc = testhref; // location.href;
  var locNavs = document.getElementsByClassName("localLi");
  for (var i = 0; i < locNavs.length; i++) {
    if (locNavs[i].getElementsByTagName('a')[0].getAttribute("href") == loc) {
      locNavs[i].className += " active";
    }
  }
}

window.onload = codeAddress;
```

```css
.active {
  border: solid lime 2px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav-menu">
  <li class="localLi menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-130"><a href="http://walter/dev/get/">walter</a>
  </li>
  <li class="localLi menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-130"><a href="http://xxxxxx/dev/get/">xxx</a>
  </li>
  <li class="localLi menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-130"><a href="http://notmedude/dev/get/">notme</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function codeAddress() {
  var loc = "http://xxxxxx/dev/get/";
  var locNavs = document.getElementsByClassName("localLi")[0].children;
  window.alert(locNavs.length);
  for (var i = 0; i < locNavs.length; i++) {

    if (locNavs[i].getAttribute("href") == loc) {
    console.log(locNavs[i])
      locNavs[i].className += "active";
    }
  }
}

window.onload = codeAddress;
```

```css
.active{
color:green;
}
```

```html
<ul id="menu-develop_menu" class="nav-menu">
  <li id="menu-item-130" class="localLi menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page 
    menu-item-130"><a href="http://xxxxxx/dev/get/">xxx</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

This code will work to change the color of anchor tag

```js
function codeAddress() {
  var loc = "http://xxxxxx/dev/get/";
  var locNavs = document.getElementsByClassName("localLi")[0].children;
  window.alert(locNavs.length);
  for (var i = 0; i < locNavs.length; i++) {
  console.log(1)
    if (locNavs[i].getAttribute("href") == loc) {
    console.log(locNavs[i])
      locNavs[i].className += "active";
    }
  }
}

window.onload = codeAddress;
```